# Prints list of images using JSP

Tags: jsp

This is my code where is prints all the list of images that I prepared. And shows it in the console. The problem is I don't know how to apply my for each statement for it to be printed out via JSP. Could any one help me regarding it?

This is my code:

```
    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    System.out.println("****************************hi: ");
    QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(WorkflowConstants.STATUS_ANY, QueryUtil.ALL_POS,
            QueryUtil.ALL_POS, null);
    System.out.println("****************************here: ");
    String imgIdStr = this.getWebContent(config.getImageCarousel(), themeDisplayObject, true);
    Long imgId = Long.parseLong(imgIdStr);
    List<Object> list = DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.getFoldersAndFileEntriesAndFileShortcuts(
            themeDisplay.getSiteGroupId(), imgId, null, true, queryDefinition);
    System.out.println("list: " + list);
    List<String> carouselImages = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Object fileNameImage: list) { 
        DLFileEntry fileEntry = (DLFileEntry) fileNameImage;
       System.out.println("File: " + fileEntry.getFileName());

       System.out.println("Path: " + "/documents/" + fileEntry.getRepositoryId() + "/" + fileEntry.getFolderId() + "/" +  fileEntry.getFileName());
       String imagePath= "/documents/" + fileEntry.getRepositoryId() + "/" + fileEntry.getFolderId() + "/" +  fileEntry.getFileName();
       System.out.println("Hey: " + imagePath);
       carouselImages.add(imagePath);
    }
    System.out.println("List of images: " + carouselImages);
```

Could anyone help me regarding a for each statement perhaps using JSP? Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Why can't you print before you add it to `carouselImages`? You can even do with out side of the loop.. but it is an unnecessary iteration, you can use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(carouselImages.toArray())`

Comment: I need to print this list of images in JSP file

Comment: The code you have is in Servelet? If it is in Servlet, you need to set the list to `request.setAttribute("imgs", carouselImages);` and then dispatch the request to JSP by using `request.getRequestDispatcher("jsppath.jsp").forward(....);`. Then in your jsp. you can use scriptlets (`<% %>`) to get the images list and write a java for loop in the scriptlets. You can google for it.